# How do I use a variable to return a named import in React?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

I want to be able to have the value of a variable (generated by a map function) be used as a named object in curly braces. I'm kind of new to React and ES6 (been teaching myself through a pet project), so I may not be asking the question properly.

I'm utilizing an NPM package (react-icons-kit) that allows me to import font icons as React modules, that then are rendered as SVGs. I have a JSON file with objects (each object has: id, name, category, description, icon) and each object has a related icon assigned to it.

When I'm rendering an  module, I have to specify the icon I want to use with curly braces. I am using a map function to process the JSON data to display each object nicely, and want to be able to dynamically create an icon using the map variable {obj.icon}.

```
import Icon from 'react-icons-kit';
import { font, clock0, html5 } from 'react-icons-kit/fa';

...

// Sample data
array = [...{"name":"Some Name","icon":"font"},{"name":"Some 
Othername","icon":"html5"},{"name":"Another Name","icon":"clock0"}...]

...

// Should render an SVG icon when use with other code
var foo = array.map((obj) => {
    console.log(obj.icon) // correctly logs font html5 clock0

    return(
        {obj.icon} // prints the value of the var fine (font html5 clock0)
        <Icon icon={clock0}/> // manually specifying works
        <Icon icon={obj.icon}/> // using a variable gives error
    );
});

...

/*================
FULL CODE (SORRY)
=================*/
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import ScrollableAnchor from 'react-scrollable-anchor'
    import { TabContent, TabPane, Nav, NavItem, NavLink, Row, Col } from 'reactstrap';
    import { Media } from 'reactstrap';
    import Icon from 'react-icons-kit';
    import { font, clockO, html5 } from 'react-icons-kit/fa';

    class Skills extends Component {

        constructor(props) {
            super(props);

            this.state = {
                activeTab: 'Coding',
            };
            this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
        }

        toggle(tab) {
            if (this.state.activeTab !== tab) {
                this.setState({
                    activeTab: tab
                });
            }
        }

        render() {
            // Skill Navigation
            let SkillNav = () => {
                let SkillNavItems = this.props.categories.map((category) => {
                    let active = (this.state.activeTab === category) ? "active" : "";
                    return (
                        <NavItem>
                            <NavLink
                                className={active}
                                onClick={() => { this.toggle(category); }}>
                                {category}
                            </NavLink>
                        </NavItem>
                    );
                });

                return (
                    <Nav pills vertical>
                        {SkillNavItems}
                    </Nav>
                );
            }
            // Different tabs of Skills
            var SkillTabs = () => {
                var SkillTab = this.props.categories.map((category) => {

                    // Separate objects by the category supplied to it
                    var SkillTabCategory = this.props.skills.filter(function (skill) {
                        return skill.category === category;
                    });
                    // Display a list of objects with the same categories
                    var SkillTabContent = SkillTabCategory.map((skill) => {
                        return (
                            <Media list>
                                <Media tag="li">
                                    <Media className="mr-5">
                                        <Icon icon={skill.icon} />
                                    </Media>
                                    <Media body>
                                        <Media heading>
                                            {skill.name}
                                        </Media>
                                        {skill.description}
                                    </Media>
                                </Media>
                            </Media>
                        );
                    });
                    return (
                        <TabPane tabId={category}>
                            <Row>
                                <Col sm="12">
                                    <h4>{category}</h4>
                                    {SkillTabContent}
                                </Col>
                            </Row>
                        </TabPane>
                    );
                });

                return (
                    <TabContent activeTab={this.state.activeTab}>
                        {SkillTab}
                    </TabContent>
                );
            }
            return (
                // Putting it all together
                <ScrollableAnchor id='skills'>
                    <div className="wrapper">
                        <div className="container">
                            <Row className="vh100 align-items-center">
                                <Col xs="4" sm="4">
                                    <SkillNav></SkillNav>
                                </Col>
                                <Col xs="12" sm="8">
                                    <SkillTabs></SkillTabs>
                                </Col>
                            </Row>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </ScrollableAnchor>
            );
        }
    }

    export default Skills;
```

Comment: Would have been better if there was entire code. The error tells that the variable `array` is not defined in the current scope where `map` is called. So either make it global or access it appropriately

Comment: I can see where you might think that, but everything else works. Using {obj.icon} by itself prints the value as you would expect (updated the code above).

Should <Icon icon={obj.icon}/> work?

Comment: if `console.log(obj.icon)` works, then the error is not in the piece of code you have posted. Should be somewhere else. Please check the error stack.

Comment: I added my full code for this section to give a complete picture. It uses reactstrap to create vertical pills with tabs. the goal of each tab is to display a category of skills. If you simply remove <Media><Icon icon={skill.icon}/></Media> it renders fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your icons names come from your json means dynamically then you need to first import all the icons from `react-icons-kit` like .

```
import * as icons from 'react-icons-kit/fa';
```

Now you can uses icons to fetch the icons runtime like

```
  const array = [{"name":"Some Othername","icon":"html5"}]
  export default ({ name }) => (
    <>
        {array.map((item)=>{
            return(
                <Icon icon={icons[item.icon]} />
            )
        })}
    </>
);
```

check running example here [Demo](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/RLoIvwBwcTsijFlQ?open=Hello.js&deferRun=1)

Comment: This seems right. The "import * as" idea is new to me, but I love it, and the utilization in the code "icon={icons[item.icon]}" looks like it could work too. It compiles flawlessly. I'm going to play with this a little more to see why I'm still getting an error.

Answer (score 0):

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zkrr402wmp)

Initialize the named-import inside the constructor function with `this.font=font;this.html5=html5;`.
Then render it with `<Icon icon={this[obj.icon]} />`